# Understanding a step in a proof to Banach-Alaoglu theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading through a proof of Banach-Alaoglu theorem in *Functional Analysis* by Jan van Neervan, and here is an excerpt of the first part of his proof.
[image]
My problem is about the assertion "by the definitions of *weak-star* and product topologies", the set
$$
k:|k_{x_0}-r_{x_0}|<\epsilon,|k_{x_1}-r_{x_1}|<\epsilon,|k_{a_0x_0+a_1x_1}-r_{ a_0x_0+a_1x_1}|<\epsilon
$$
is open in the product topology of $K$. How does the openness of the set has to do with the *weak-star* topologies? Isn't it directly follows from the product topology?

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is weird, I think. At this stage only the product topology is used. But in the end the proof is about $\overline{B_{X^*}}$ with the weak$^*$-topology, and that will be addressed by discussing that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, with the weak$^*$-topology in its domain, and the product topology in its codomain.